# can a user view vb.net settings in application

Tags: vb.net

I am creating a VB.net application and including my database credentials in the settings of the project, so to access i use:

```
My.Settings.SettingName
```

Is there any way a user using the application can view these settings?

I am worried about someone being able to log into the database if they ever manage to see the settings?

Comment: Settings are just stored in an easily readable XML file.  The location can be a tiny bit hard to find, but thats all.

Comment: so if a user looked, they could see the settings?

Comment: @charlie Yes, assuming they manage to find the XML file that contains the settings, they would be able to read them.

Comment: Yes, they can find, read and modify the settings.

Comment: VB.NET is a language. This answer requires knowledge of the platform. IE, Web or Desktop application.

Comment: Note: If you want to save the credentials and be able to modify them, you could always encrypt the strings. I can give you an encryption code if you want to.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Application users can not see these settings.  The only way to see the settings is to look at the code as a developer.

EDIT:
In my humble experience, the best choice for hiding a connection string in your app, considering the environment I work in, is to hide it in the vb code.  You can make a database utilities class, and put your methods and properties there - methods being connect, execute commands etc, and a private property which is your connection string that other methods in the class use.

Other people can see the connection string, like other developers, or people who are browsing around the same files you have access to, but upon deployment, it will be very difficult for someone to extract the connection string out of yourapp.exe.

Comment: These settings are stored in an XML file on disk. Anyone with the will and a little knowledge can easily find them.

Comment: Are you serious, "The only way to see the settings is to look at the code as a developer"? Anyone can see these, they are in clear text on disk...

Comment: If I'm in a windows form app using it, clicking it, reading it - or if I'm on a web site using it, the settings are not exposed through the app unless the developer chooses to expose them (like web.config, app.config).  If I want to go outside of the app and look through app files, of course I can find an xml file and read it.  "a user using the application" is what I am speaking to.  If I'm in the file system, I'm not using the app anymore.  But yes, the xml they find while browsing files can be used to access the database.